# Compare web and DB tables: code skips DB records

Tags: vbscript, automated-tests, qtp

I have a webtable separated to 50+ pages, 20 records per page. Need to verify it against sql db.

Pages are represented as links in bottom of table like this:

[image]

Now, my code clicks next page (current page+1) correctly and verifies pages 1 to 10 with no problem. But when it clicks last link (`...`) and goes to page 11, it skips 20 records from the DB table and starts verifying record 201 from webtable with record 221 from DB. What is wrong with it?

Here is the code I have:

```
set PagesLink=description.Create
PagesLink("micclass").Value = "Link"
PagesLink("html tag").Value = "A"

Do Until DBMaintenanceRS.EOF
Set PagesCollection = .WbfGrid("html tag:=TABLE","html id:=cphBody_GridView1").ChildObjects(PagesLink) 'Get links to pages. 10 links to pages are showed in bottom of table.

print PagesCollection.Count

For pc = 0 To PagesCollection.Count-1 'start pages loop

For rc = 2 to .WbfGrid("html tag:=TABLE","html id:=cphBody_GridView1").RowCount-1 'start table rows loop
        For cc = 2 To .WbfGrid("html tag:=TABLE","html id:=cphBody_GridView1").ColumnCount(1) 'start table columns loop
            wCell = .WbfGrid("html tag:=TABLE","html id:=cphBody_GridView1").GetCellData(rc, cc)
            dbCell = DBMa

intenanceRS.Fields(cc-2)
                    If trim(dbCell) = trim(wCell) Then
                        Print "Pass"
                    Else
                        print "FAIL::: ID="&.WbfGrid("html tag:=TABLE","html id:=cphBody_GridView1").GetCellData(rc, 2)&"-Column='"&.WbfGrid("html tag:=TABLE","html id:=cphBody_GridView1").GetCellData(1, cc)&"'-Value="&wCell&"-=-VS DB: "&dbCell
                    End If

            Next

            cc=""
            wcell=""
            dbcell=""
            DBMaintenanceRS.MoveNext
        Next
    rc=""
    print pc&"-=-"& PagesCollection(pc).GetROProperty("innertext")

    If pc=0 Then
        If NOT(PagesCollection(pc).GetROPRoperty("innertext")="...") Then
            PagesCollection(pc).Click
        End If
Else
    PagesCollection(pc).Click
End If
.Sync
wait 1

Set PagesCollection = .WbfGrid("html tag:=TABLE","html id:=cphBody_GridView1").ChildObjects(PagesLink)
Next
print "Next 10 pages"
pc=0
Set PagesCollection = .WbfGrid("html tag:=TABLE","html id:=cphBody_GridView1").ChildObjects(PagesLink)
print DBMaintenanceRS.Fields(0)
Loop
```

Comment: You have 3 `For` loops nested in each other.  When you're clicking the `...` your code is treating it as a new page, but with no object rowcount, there's nothing to compare against the DB data, so those 10 records get skipped over.

Comment: any suggestion how to avoid that?

Comment: @Salek When you click in the link `...`, what happens? Are the link for pages 1 to 10 still visible? Or we only the links from 10-20 followed by `...` visible?

Comment: Each time the `...` is clicked, next 10 links appear (or previous 10, if the `...` from left is clicked).

Answer (score 0):

Your row-count variable (`rc`) is counting the rows globally but the web page only contains the current *window* of rows (21..40 for example) so what you think of as row 21 is actually the first row of the current `WbfGrid`.

You need to have separate counters for DB rows and `WbfGrid` rows.

Comment: any suggestion how to avoid that?

Comment: @Salek have two separate variables and zero one out after clicking `... `